# Как удалить документ и вернуть оставшееся документы mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Есть модель Users, хочу удалить один из документов данной модели с помощью

```
findByIdAndRemove({idDoc})
.then((doc) => {
res.send(doc) // ожидаемо возвращается удаленный элемент, а как вернуть оставшиеся элементы?
})
```

Comment: после удаления сделать запрос, который извлечёт "все оставшиеся" и вернуть их

Comment: в том то и дело, что была какая-то option, позволяющая сразу указать возврат остатка... findByIdAndRemove({idDoc}, {option})